# Yii nested module settings

Tags: php, yii

I need to create multiple application using yii and it seems that modules is my best solution, because I don't want to copy paste components, extension on other yii project.

My project consist of client, applicant, admin and they all have different functionalities inside my application

I tried this structure in Yii

```
modules
 -> client
     -> modules
          -> module1
          -> module2
 -> applicant
     -> modules
          -> module1
          -> module2
 -> admin
     -> controllers
          -> site
     -> modules
          -> module1
          -> module2
          -> module3
```

but when I called domain.com/admin/module1/default/index it says 404 error even I have default controller and index view on my source,

I tried domain.com/admin/site/login it works fine,
is there something I missing here....

here's my config for modules

```
'modules'=>array(
        'admin' => array(
            'modules' => array(
                'user'

            )
        )
    ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the nested module alias path :

```
'modules'=>array(
        'admin' => array(
            'modules' => array(
                'user'=>array(
                   'class'=>'application.modules.user.UserModule' //just an example put yours
                    'components'=>array(), 
                 )

            )
        )
    ),
```

You can also configure that in the module class init method just use [setModules()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModule#setModules-detail)